# Problem with bpy.ops.sculpt.mask_expand

Tags: python, scripting

I want create simple button.

```
class Interactive_mask(bpy.types.Operator):
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
        bpy.ops.sculpt.sculptmode_toggle()        
        bpy.ops.sculpt.mask_expand(invert=True, smooth_iterations=2, use_normals=False, keep_previous_mask=False,)
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

And I have problem with bpy.ops.sculpt.mask_expand When I press my button i have such a error
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.sculpt.mask_expand()failed, context is incorrect
What I should change or add to code ?

Answer (score 0):

**Not in sculpt mode.**

Result in python console of changing absolute mode of object to 'SCULPT' followed by toggling mode

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
{'FINISHED'}

>>> bpy.ops.sculpt.sculptmode_toggle()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.mode
'OBJECT'
```

hence out of context, since `bpy.ops.sculpt.*` operators require sculpt mode for context.

Remove toggle to remain in sculpt mode or  move to  the last line to toggle.

Tip

Making a poll method for your operator returning false for selected objects that cannot be sculpted will disable button in UI and remove it from context operator search.